# How to sort a translated list in Angular 5 (ngx-translate)

Tags: angular, sorting, ngx-translate

Let's say I have the following simple html-code (Angular 5, ngx-translate):

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div>{{item | translate}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the list 'items' from the backend via http-get.

My Question is: How can I sort the list of items by their translated values?

Example:

items:

```
[ "lbl_a", "lbl_b", "lbl_c" ]
```

with the translations:

```
{
    "lbl_a": "tree",
    "lbl_b": "zoo",
    "lbl_c": "car"
}
```

Then i want to display:

```
car
tree
zoo
```

(sorted by the alphabet)

Answer (score 3):

You can either create a pipe or sort the items when you get them.

```
this.service.getTranslatedItems().subscribe(items => {
  this.items = items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
});
```

With the pipe

```
transform(items: string[]) {
  return items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
}
```

And in your HTML (pipe only)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | yourPipeName">
    <div>{{item | translate}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You annot use the built-in pipes to filter or to [sort data](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

But, you can achive that by writing your own pipe. Just translate and then sort the data.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort by [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items | orderBy : 'columnname']"">
        <div>{{item | translate}}</div>
    </div>
```